# Is it safe to use device name such as sda to create md and ZFS RAID array?

Tags: zfs, mdadm, md

In md we can scan or assemble an array using UUID:

`mdadm --assemble "/dev/md/raid5" --uuid "b9a09187:a1ac838f:b4e90395:d6293c19"`

And in ZFS, we have a service for that purpose:

`rc-service zfs-import start # OpenRC on Alpine Linux`

Is it safe to use device name such as `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` to create `md` and `ZFS` RAID array? If the names are changed after a reboot, will the command `mdadm --assemble` and the service `zfs-import` be able to read the filesystem header on each disk and detect them?

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to ZFS, but for `mdadm` when you *create* an array you use the device names.  This will write a UUID to each component of the array.  And it's this UUID that will be used to reconstruct the array on reboot.

eg on my Rocky8 machine I have the following entries in `/etc/mdadm.conf`

```
ARRAY /dev/md1 level=raid1 num-devices=2 UUID=319367a0:0bf67279:3b7ded8a:cad6a06c
ARRAY /dev/md2 level=raid1 num-devices=2 UUID=49e9de19:e56e702e:dda216de:e6a7ee85
ARRAY /dev/md3 level=raid1 num-devices=2 UUID=f3d8b1d9:2b70cea8:b8a23691:560ed399
ARRAY /dev/md68 level=raid6 num-devices=8 UUID=1784ac2f:cec3f0ec:e0096e7e:43dfd8ba
```

The `md1` array was created with

```
mdadm --create /dev/md1 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1
```

On reboot the `md` subsystem will scan all devices looking for raid components with the relevant UUID and rebuild the array.  It won't matter if the device entry names have changed; it's the UUID that matters.